# Detect support for drawImage from video element

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to write a video viewer that draws parts of a video element onto an HTML canvas using `drawImage`, but this is not supported on some devices (iOS, for example). Rather than sniffing the browser/OS, I'd rather do feature detection and fall back to just playing the normal video on these devices. Is there a reliable way to test for this functionality?

Comment: As far as I know there is not besides trying to draw one frame and then inspecting the results using context.getImageData() ... slow

Answer (score -1):

check this:

```
function isCanvasSupported()
{
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  return !!(canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'));
};
```

This will return true if canvas is supported otherwise false.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I am trying to detect support for drawing to a canvas from a HTML video element.

Comment: Then i guess only solution is you have to check for browser and os details, Which you dont want to do.